# R Interactively identify points from same dataset between multiple plots

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I have an R dataframe and some scatterplots and barplots created from them.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,3,8,2,5,6,2,7,4,4),var2 = runif(n = 10),var3 = runif(n=10,min = 10,max=50),var4 = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)))
plot(df$var1,df$var2)
plot(df$var2,df$var3)
barplot(df$var3,names.arg=df$var4)
```

[image]

If I am interested in a point on the first plot, I would like to identify that point on the second, third or multiple other plots. I would like to be able to do this interactively (for example using mouse-over hover effects) in a shareable rmarkdown document.

How can one go about doing this in R either using base graphics, ggplot or even something like shiny/rCharts? Any examples/links would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess `ggvis` + `shiny` could be another option. AFAIK, base graphics and ggplot2 do not produce interactive graphics.

Comment: You could create a custom htmlwidget to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `identify` function to locate the points in a scatterplot interactively in base `R`.

As an example, you can identify the pairs of variables in the second plot with

```
identify(df$var2,df$var3)
```

Once you have clicked on the point of interest, hit the Esc key. The row number corresponding to the point on which you clicked will be displayed in the console and on the graph.

In this case I have clicked on a point near `var2=0.5` and `var3=30`. The result shows that this is point number 2 in the dataset.

[image]

```
> identify(df$var2,df$var3) # Hit Esc key once you have selected the point.
[1] 2 # <- this is the result: the index (row) number of the selected point
#> df[2,]
#  var1     var2     var3 var4
#2    3 0.481937 29.54026    A
```

For more information see `?identify`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is all very good. But, can you identify one point in 2 or more plots simultaneously? And can this be shared as an rmarkdown document or shiny app?